# Print list1 with list2 python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I dont know how to search this code in internet so I ask here
My code :

```
# This code is in Tes.py
n = [str]*3 
x = [int]*3
MyLib.name(n)
MyLib.number(x)
MyLib.Result(n,x)

# This code in MyLib.py with 3 def
def name(data) :
    for i in range (3) :
        n[i] = str(input("Enter Name : ")

def number(data) :
    for s in range (3) :
        x[i] = int(input("Enter Number : ")

def result(data1,data2) :
    for i in data1 :
        for i in data2 :
            print("Your Name",n,"Your Number",x)

examples :
input 1 : Jack
          Rino
          Gust
input 2 : 1232
          1541
          2021
output what I want : Your Name Jack Your Number 1232
                     Your Name Rino Your Number 1541
                     Your Name Gust Your Number 2021

output that i got :  Your Name Jack Your Number 1232
                     Your Name Jack Your Number 1541
                     Your Name Jack Your Number 2021
                     Your Name Rino Your Number 1232
                     Your Name Rino Your Number 1541
                     Your Name Rino Your Number 2021
                     Your Name Gust Your Number 1232
                     Your Name Gust Your Number 1541
                     Your Name Gust Your Number 2021
```

How to get output like what I want, I want to search it in the google but I dont know what I must type.

Comment: I'm edited it, sorry for lack of detail

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
for i in range(min(len(n), len(x))):
    print("Your Name",n[i],"Your Number",x[i])
```

Comment: I tried it, but error "IndexError: list index out of range", any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 3
n = [str]*total
x = [int]*total
for i in range (total):
    n[i] = str(input("Enter Name : "))

for i in range (total):
    x[i] = int(input("Enter Number : "))

for i in range (total):
        print("Your Name",n[i],"Your Number",x[i])
```

If you give this code the input you mentioned, it will show the desired result. As you wrote two loops,

```
 for i in n :
    for i in x :
```

your print will be triggered 3*3 = 9 times! You just need one single loop, since at the both input you are taking same number of inputs (3 names and 3 numbers!). Even I would say why do you need 3 loops? why not just this:

```
total = 3
n = [str]*total
x = [int]*total
for i in range (total):
    n[i] = str(input("Enter Name : "))
    x[i] = int(input("Enter Number : "))
    print("Your Name",n[i],"Your Number",x[i])
```

Comment: I got error "IndexError: list index out of range", any suggest ?

Comment: I didn't change my code, i just add [i] in print("Your Name",n[i],"Your Number",x[i])

Comment: Just adding [i] won't solve your problem. You have to rewrite the loop that you are using before printing. And also why you are using the same variable `i` in the nested loop? And also in the `def number(data)` function you used `s` as the loop variable but used `x[i]` to assign numbers!